# Thunderbird calendar alerts are no longer persistent system-wide stay-on-screen notifications

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, notification, calendar

In 16.04 when there was a calendar reminder for an event in Thunderbird/Lightning it would give a system-wide pop up reminder. These would appear at the forefront of the screen no matter what application was currently being used, even in Thunderbird was minimized or right after waking the computer from sleep. Now in 18.04, if Thunderbird is minimized these notification popups do not appear. Instead, I have to go to the sidebar and I can see the notification window when I move the cursor over the thunderbird icon.

Why do these notifications no longer appear at the front of the screen? Is there any way to change this behavior in 18.04? I tested Evolution and the calendar alerts there are system-wide pop-ups, as Thunderbird was in 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found installing the [NoAnnoyance gnome shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/) worked. Instead of a popup saying a new window is ready (the thunderbird notificaiton window) the new window is brought to the front.

Comment: Link to shell extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The notifications are no longer appearing on top for me.  I leave the rest of the answer here in case it is the basis for a real answer

---

The solution appears to be to integrate Thunderbird with the Gnome clock (no, I have no idea why either).

Install [EDS Calendar Integration](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/eds-calendar-integration/), restart Thunderbird, and it all appears to work.

Installing the extension:

- Select "Tools | Add-ons" menu
- Type "EDS Calendar Integration" into the search bar (top right)
- Click the "Add to Thunderbird" button
- Click the button to say you trust the author
- Click the "Restart now" button on the top right if you like (which I missed)